# Cannot change hover color for links

Tags: css, links

I am using twentytwelve and a child theme at http://fosit.staging.wpengine.com/.

I would like *all* links in my website to have this dark blue color on hover: #0f3647

The only links where this color is working is the post titles. These links, however, stay #21759b on hover no matter what I try:

- After a post, the links for "Continue reading" and "X Replies"
- The links under the "Recent Posts" widget on the right
- The "Reply" links in the comment area under a post

Below is the exhaustive list I've tried adding to my child theme's style.css, and none of them have any effect. Somewhere, deep in the soul-sucking abyss of CSS, the hover property is being overridden.

I tried a giant hammer:

```
a:hover {
    color: #0f3647 !important;
}
```

And I tried these ...

For "Continue reading" and "X Replies":

```
.more-link a:hover {
    color: #0f3647;
}

.leave-reply a:hover { 
    color: #0f3647;    
}

.reply-count a:hover {
    color: #0f3647;  
}
```

For the Recent Posts widget:

```
.widget-area .widget a:hover {
    color: #0f3647;
}
```

For the "Reply" in the comments area:

```
.comments-link a:hover {
    color: #0f3647;
}
```

I also tried:

```
.site-header h1 a:hover,
.site-header h2 a:hover {
    color: #0f3647;
}

.main-navigation a:hover,
.main-navigation a:focus {
    color: #0f3647;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is not WordPress issue but CSS, so it's off-topic here. Now on your problem. There is a `span` element in each of your link tags and span color is overriding the link color. For example in read more link there is a `span` with class `.meta-nav`. You will need to remove color for these classes. You will have to do the same for all other.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid all this redundancy if you analyze carefully and see where the error is originating. Chrome developer tools or Firefox is great to help you debugging. You are actually trying to style the link, but the link has a `span` inside of it, each with its own class.

A quick and dirty solution is that on line 101 of [your child theme](http://fosit.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/style.css?ver=4.3.1) you can add

```
span.meta-nav:hover, .reply-count:hover, .rpwwt-post-title:hover{
    color: #0f3647;    
}
```

Comment: I added a "." in front of rpwwt and it works great. Thank you. I was using Firebug which is how I identified those possibilities in the first place, but being new to CSS I made some coding errors. For example, when `.reply-count a:hover { color: #0f3647; }` didn't work, I moved on to a different element, when in fact this would have worked: `.reply-count:hover`.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot the class selector for .rpwwt-post-title :) Great that it worked.